# A simple exponential limit

Tags: limits

Calculating this limit

${(\frac{3nc_n}{2nc_n})^{1/n}}$ where n tends infinity

the question gives no information about $c_n$ which makes the question easier for me
I simply wrote it as

$(3/2)^\frac{1}{n}$  which gives answer 1 .

Is there some error in question or a basic wrong thing I'm doing as answer is not this

I've solved it in a general way of solving $a^{1/n}$ which explains e

[image]

Comment: Assuming $c_n \ne 0$ then $n\cdot c_n$ in the numerator and denominator "cancel out' so you must calculate $(\frac 32)^{\frac 1n}$.  I don't know why you wrote it as $e^{\frac 32 - 1}\cdot \frac 1n$ which gives an answer of $0$.  But $\frac 1n \to 0$ so $(\frac 32)^{\frac 1n}\to (\frac 32)^0 = 1$.

Comment: could you explain what you meant by "I wrote $e^{\frac 32-1}\times \frac 1n$ and what you mean by "which gives answer $1$".  Neither of those statements seem correct to me and I don't understand why you did either of them.

Comment: @fleablood does it work now

Comment: This question makes no sense, something is wrong.

Comment: Does $lt$ mean "limit".  I can only conclude the problem has typographical error.  $nc_n$ cancel out and $\lim (\frac 32)^{\frac \1n} = (\frac 32)^0 = 1$ and so $a = b$ so $a=b=1$ and $a+b=2; ab=1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I better delete it even I think its wrong

Comment: @fleablood I guess its 3ncn and 2ncn

Comment: @Anusha Where is the problem from? School? If yes you should definitely ask your teacher for further insight.

Comment: @vitamind I guess I got the typo it should be $3nC_n$ and $2nC_n$ can u help now?

Comment: Isn't this the same problem? Please include the new question in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert it in an exponential function. Also I can't understand what you mean by "Is there some error in question or a basic wrong thing I'm doing as answer is not this". But here is how I solved the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(\frac{3nc_n}{2nc_n}\right)^{1/n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{1/n}}={\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{0}}=1$$

If that's not what you're asking please tell me in the comments. I will then delete my answer.

Now after uploading the image I'm even more confused. We know that $\frac{a}{b}$ is equal to $1$. The only numbers $a$ and $b$ that satisfy this relation are by definition $a=b=1$.
So $a+b$ must be $2$.

Comment: I got answer 1 but its given to be wrong

Comment: Are you sure that you typed the limit in correctly? You, @fleablood and me got the same answer so the problem must be typed in incorrectly.

Comment: So... what does the text say the answer is.  (I suspect you are not stating the actual question)

Comment: Should I put a screenshot?